# How to create Repair disc for Windows 7 64 bit?

Tags: windows-7-restore

When I try to Restore System image from backup I've got this error:
"The selected system image cannot be restored in this recovery environment"
Browsing this Forum I noticed that folks found that this message could be when one created 32 bit Repair disc and tries to Restore 64 bit OS.
In my case I created a disc on Windows 7 Enterprise PC. I am trying to Restore Windows 7 64 bit machine.
My question: when user creates a Repair disc does he has the option to specify 32 vs. 64 bit?
I simply thought that since I'm on 64 bit system it'll create 64 bit Repair disc ... but maybe I'm wrong and I created 32 bit Disc...
Could someone please highlight it?
Thanks

Comment: Just download the Windows 7 disk, it has the exact same version of WinRE, that the recovery disk has

Comment: " when user creates a Repair disc does he has the option to specify 32 vs. 64 bit? " No it must be made on the same bit version of the OS you need to repair.

Comment: Similar issue...http://superuser.com/questions/301910/restoring-windows-system-image-backup-to-a-different-hard-disk

Comment: Well ... I created Repair disc on Windows 7 Enterprise i.e. it run 64 bit. Hence I should be all set ... just wonder if it provide options 32 vs. 64

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem in my case:
I created Repair disc on Windows 7 32 bit but tried to use this disc and restore image on Windows 7 64
After I created another Repair disc on 64 bit machine I was able to restore the image.